# Is it possible to store HHVM bytecode as a file?

Tags: php, compilation, bytecode, hhvm

Is there a way to save HHVM bytecode as a file, since HHVM uses JIT bytecode compilation instead of compiling? If not, are there any alternatives for modern PHP versions (5.5,5.6)?

Comment: HUH? Save it as a file? Save what? The bytecode isn't compiled. It's just an intermediary representation...

Comment: Well, technically, it's actually saved as a file: HHVM uses SQLite for caching HHBC. SQLite uses files for storing the mini-databases. This is the reason why you don't lose your cached bytecodes if you restart the computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate bytecode, which is saved in internal SQLite database and then switch on Repo.Authoritative mode, under which HHVM will only use bytecode from SQLite db and never touch source .php files. See http://hhvm.com/blog/4061/go-faster

Comment: Is there one Database for each project or are all projects stored in one database?

Comment: Everything is in a single database. One way would be tu run separate HHVM instance for each project and then let the nginx or whatever webserver you use do the magic to pass FastCGI requests of each vhost / path to a different HHVM instance.