# Can PHP be considered a compiled language when running on the HHVM?

Tags: php, hhvm

According to the [HHVM website](http://hhvm.com/):

> Rather than directly interpret or compile PHP code directly to C++, HHVM compiles Hack and PHP into an intermediate bytecode. This bytecode is then translated into x64 machine code dynamically at runtime by a just-in-time (JIT) compiler.

Does this mean that PHP code running on the HHVM, like Java running on the JVM, can be considered compiled?
Or is it just like .pyc Python files where the original code is translated to interpreter-ready intermediate code?

Comment: "This bytecode is then translated into x64 machine code dynamically at runtime"  What does that tell you?

Comment: depends on your definition of "compiled". it's been compiled from php->bytecode, but then the JIT **compiler** takes that bytecode and converts it to machine code. so if you define compiler as "takes source code and generates machine code),then no, hhvm is not a compiler and php is not "compiled" by it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to store HHVM bytecode as a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815519/is-it-possible-to-store-hhvm-bytecode-as-a-file)